# How to force a TableLayout to fit the whole screen?

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to create a basic tablelayout at runtime in android. I have tried every combination of Wrap_Content, Match_Parent, and set weight but nothing seems to work.

Essentially I want this:

```
        Title
```

Text A ***************** Text A1

Text B ***************** Text B1

Text C ***************** Text C1

Where the *** means blank space (Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to format it). I want this to continue such that it fills the screen both horizontally and vertically. Currently I am able to make it fit the screen horizontally but it leaves a large blank space on the bottom.

My XML is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blackboard"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Classes"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayTableForClasses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What I essentially need is a way for the font to scale such that it will fill the entire screen vertically without wrapping around. What would be best is this case would be to have the font size be the largest possible without causing wrap-around and then the margins between the different TextViews to be increased such that it will fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change width and height in the parent layout first.
For example if you use RelativeLayout you need to change your layout properties like:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and then in you TableLayout, you can use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Use this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let me edit it with my new XML. It still does not work. What I really want is a way to make the setMargins(15,15,15,15) in a way that it will fit the whole screen verticially (aka make the verticle margin bigger such that it will fit the whole screen with the items in the for loop).

Comment: I've put another code. I used LinearLayout with different orientation to manage TextViews